# Which Writer do I need for PDF Documents in FME 2014?

Tags: fme-form, pdf

I have successfully used the ImageFetcher transformer to download many images from a URL by using a JPG writer. Now I want to do this with PDF Documents, but have the problem that the Adobe 3D PDF writer and Adobe Geospatial PDF don´t write the outputs to a file.
Here is the log. 
How can I use the HTTPfetcher to download pdf documents?

```
    f_39(CreationFactory): Created 1 features
f_40(TeeFactory): Cloned 1 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
MULTI_WRITER: multi_writer_id `1': Started outputting features
Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for writer named `PDF2D'
Loaded module 'PDF2D' from file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FME\plugins/pdf/pdf.dll'
FME API version of module 'PDF2D' matches current internal version (3.7 20140327)
FME Configuration: No destination coordinate system set
FME API version of module 'PDF2D' matches current internal version (3.7 20140327)
Writer `PDF2D_1' of type `PDF2D' using group definition keyword `PDF2D_1_DEF'
FME API version of module 'PDF2D' matches current internal version (3.7 20140327)
Could not open output file for writing.  Please verify that the file is not open in other applications or that the file is not read-only
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Feature output statistics for `PDF2D' writer using keyword `PDF2D_1':
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
               Features Written
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
==============================================================================
Total Features Written                                                       0
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
FME Session Duration: 51.7 seconds. (CPU: 3.3s user, 0.3s system)
END - ProcessID: 8464, peak process memory usage: 103668 kB, current process memory usage: 103252 kB

A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
Program Terminating

Translation FAILED.
```

Comment: FME does not have a PDF Reader only a Writer. http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000chmWAAQ

Comment: I managed to do this without creating a writer at all. In fact the httpfetcher transformer allows you to save the output directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download files from a website and then do a search to locate all PDFs within the file set.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPFetcher retrieves the information into an attribute, so use the AttributeFileWriter transformer to write that attribute out to the file system. If it's already a PDF then you shouldn't need to use the PDF Writer.